# Capybara fill_in not entering all the text

Tags: rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chromedriver 2.30 with capybara 2.14.4 under rspec 3.6.0

```
fill_in "total-amount", with: "33"
expect(find_by_id("total-amount").value).to have_text("33")
click_on "create_btn"
```

Sometimes I will get the error

```
1) Create purchase with discount transaction creates a Sales Return Transaction
     Failure/Error: expect(find_by_id("total-amount").value).to have_text("33")
       expected to find text "33" in "3"
     # ./spec/integration/transactions/create_purchase_with_discount_spec.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It is like fill_in is entering the characters one at a time. How do I get fill_in to put all the characters in at once?

**Update**

I tried

```
expect(page).to have_field('total-amount', with: "33")
```

but got this flaky error

```
expected to find field "total-amount" with value "33" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

It's finding the element, but the value hasn't been entered in there yet even though the fill_in line is before it. I'm using material design and there are calculations going on all these fields which may affect the time in which these elements update.

**Update**

Changed default_max_wait_time to 20seconds, still get the problem

**Update**

If I put sleeps around the fill_in "total-amount", with: "33" like so;

```
sleep 1
fill_in "total-amount", with: "33"
sleep 1
expect(find_by_id("total-amount").value).to have_text("33")
click_on "create_btn"
```

This works, but putting sleeps is wrong! So I still need a way to check that what I've entered into the material design box is actually in there and set to the angular model before continuing.

Comment: Usually this type of error is caused by some JS on the page taking the focus away while the characters are being input.  Try sleeping for a few seconds before calling `fill_in` to see if the issue goes away.  Additionally, you should not be calling `have_text` on the string value since that causes the string returned by `value` to be parsed as an HTML document then compared, which is unpredicatable. You should be doing either  `expect(find_by_id("total-amount").value).to eq "33"` or better yet  `expect(page).to have_field('total-amount', with: '33')`

Comment: The `expect(page).to have_field('total-amount', with: "33")` line you're running will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the condition to match -- What type of calculations are going on with the field?  Try setting `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10`  and seeing if that cures the issue.  If it doesn't then you're going to have to look at the JS attached to that input and see if it can be improved to not miss keypresses.  Also did you try sleeping a few seconds before the `fill_in` to see if it's just that the JS on your page hasn't fully initialized before fill_in occurs

Comment: I did try a sleep before and after and found that placing the sleep after seems to have worked. I don't want to put a sleep in obviously but it did prove that perhaps the calculations are delaying the text appearing. I have adjusted the default_max_wait_time to 20 and still get the issues. I'll have a look at the JS on the ng-change of that element to see if I can fix it that way.

Comment: You might be running into https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771&q=sendkeys&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 2):

Chromedriver with Selenium does not support well unfocused fill in

user experience for any input have 2 steps:

1. click or select by keyboard some input
2. enter any data

to make your tests done, use this code:

```
area = find("#total-amount").click # user usually click before input
area.send_keys "33"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're bumping into the race condition mentioned in the *Capybara, a patient animal* section of [this](http://www.simplybusiness.co.uk/about-us/tech/2015/02/flaky-tests-and-capybara-best-practices/) post.

I can't find a canonical list of *methods which wait* provided by the Capybara docs, but based on the list provided in that blog post, `#has_field?` *should* wait and prevent the race condition you're seeing.

`page.has_field?('total-amount', :with => '33')`

Comment: I have tried page.has_field and it doesn't seem to matter what I put in the 'with' section the test just continues on. ie: I put in page.has_field?('total-amount', :with => '13') before and the test didn't show an error.

Comment: @map7 has_field? just returns a boolean it doesn’t raise an error if things don’t match, for that you need to use the have_field matcher as in my comment